# What is Pending Intent In Android?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

What is a `Pending Intent` in Android?

I am new in android.. Can any one please tell me what is a `Pending Intent` and where to use it?
I want exact definitions of `Pending Intent`.

Comment: Pending Intent is generally use for push notification message on action redirection screen.

Answer (score 0):

**A pending intent is a token that you give to another application** (e.g., notification manager, alarm manager or other 3rd party applications), which allows this other application to use the permissions of your application to execute a predefined piece of code. A Pending Intent specifies an action to take in the future. It lets you pass a future Intent to another application and allow that application to execute that Intent as if it had the same permissions as your application, whether or not your application is still around when the Intent is eventually invoked. have a look on following links to get more detail

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html#pendingintent

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-launch-pending-intent.html